# What file encoding is used by SVN?

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn

We files in svn which we extract in byte format with a webservice.

I am trying to move us over to getting these files from an S3 bucket.

When we extract the file from svn it comes out in bytes which we later decode using LZ4.
Like this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(LZHelper.ReadFromLZ4Stream(bytes returned by svn))
```

However, the file for our bucket is just uploaded without compression or anything. I extracted the bytes and tried to encode them so they would match the svn version.  I assumed it would be UTF8 as that is the decode used above but it does not seem to match.

In this function, not one of the compressedByte arrays matches the svn reply.

```
   public byte[] GetFile(string pstrPath)
        {
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("blah", "blah blah", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.whoknows);
            GetObjectRequest gRequest = new GetObjectRequest();
            gRequest.BucketName = "test";
            gRequest.Key = "the file path and name";
            string contents;
            GetObjectResponse gresponse = s3Client.GetObjectAsync(gRequest).Result;
            byte[] compressedBytes;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                gresponse.ResponseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                compressedBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            }

            byte[] compressedBytes1 = LZ4Codec.Wrap(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(contents));
            byte[] compressedBytes2 = LZ4Codec.Wrap(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents));
            byte[] compressedBytes3 = LZ4Codec.Wrap(Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(contents));
            byte[] compressedBytes4 = LZ4Codec.Wrap(Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(contents));
            byte[] compressedBytes5 = LZ4Codec.Wrap(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(contents));
            byte[] compressedBytes6 = LZ4Codec.Wrap(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contents));
            
            byte[] svnres = Channel.GetFile(pstrPath);

            return Channel.GetFile(pstrPath);
        }
```

Is there a way I can find out what encoding these files are using?
Ideally I will change the file upload to be this encoding but I cannot do that unless I work out what encoding svn is using.

Comment: Is data binary? Using Encoding with binary data will corrupt the data.  You can use a BinaryReader to read the byte[].

Comment: @jdweng, thanks.  I had a go at changing it to read in via a BinaryReader but the result was the same and still different to the svn byte stream :-(